# jquery - how to set and retrieve values from array stored using data()

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to create an array, assign it to a div-element, push() a value and retrieve it again at a later stage.

Can someone tell me, what I'm missing...:

```
// set Array
// $(this) is the HTML-element which should get array assigned
var stack = [],
    stack.push('#'+$(this).find(':jqmData(role="page")').attr('id')),

$(this).data( stack );
```

Using

```
console.log( $(this).data(stack) );
```

I'm getting back the whole HTML element, while

```
console.log( $(this).data(stack[0] OR stack.length) );
```

don't work.

How can I access the elements that I (presumably...) pushed into the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name your data. For example:

```
$("div").data("stack", []); //This sets the data key "stack" to an empty array
$("div").data("stack").push(123); //This retrieves the array and pushes a number to the array
console.log($("div").data("stack")); //This prints the array
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign data to an element you have to give it a key to index by.

**PUT**

```
$(this).data('stack', stack);
```

**GET**

```
var stack = $(this).data('stack');
```

Answer (score 0):

Data takes a key, value pair. You're not passing in the key.

```
$(this).data('stack', stack );
```

Then to retrieve it:

```
$(this).data('stack');
```